# How to Control the audio volume which is playing from Service?

Tags: android, service, android-mediaplayer, volume

My apps playing two audio, first from service and second from activity. I want to decrease the volume of first audio when second audio is playing. After stop the second audio, the volume of first audio should be increases.

Comment: Which Apis are you using for playback?

Comment: Using Android MediaPlayer and audio is in my raw folder.

Answer (score 3):

MediaPlayer has methods for that. It sets volume for left and right channel.
Unmuted:

```
mediaPlayerA.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
```

mute the other player

```
mediaPlayerB.setVolume(0.0f, 0.0f);
```

Comment: Simple but helpful. Thanks ;.)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you implemented your `MediaPlayer` to coincide with your service, but in my *test*, I created an instance of `MediaPlayer` within my service class. In order to control the volume of the `MediaPlayer` instance of the service class, outside of it's service class, I set the `MediaPlayer` instance as a static member.

So in my service class i did this:

```
static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
```

In my activity (which has it's own audio playing) I did this:

```
MyOwnService.mediaPlayer.setVolume(0.1f, 0.1f);
```

So, when I jumped into my activity, I used this statement first, before playing the activity's audio. Notice I did not mute (0.0f, 0.0f) it. You can play around with your floats until it suits your needs. It ranges between 0.0f - 1.0f.

In my Activity, I also implemented the `MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener`, so that I know when the audio for the Activity was complete. This interface has one method to implement, `onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)`. This method gets called once the audio is complete.

So in my activity I also did this:

```
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    MyOwnService.mediaPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

Here, I then raised the volume of the service music back to max, since the audio playback within it's activity has now completed.

Again, this was all in test, and I wouldn't like to expose a static member just like that (in a published app), I would encapsulate it some how, so there's some type of access control.

I hope this was helpful.